# Space on top on IE7

Tags: html, wordpress

My site looks great in other browsers, but there's extra space on top in IE7.

Screenshot:

[image]

Site: http://bottlelesscoolerreview.bottleless.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue.  Between `#topbarLeft` and `#topbarCenter`, there is an `&nbsp;`.  What this causes to happen is the rendering of a space after `#topbarLeft`, pushing `#topbarCenter` and `#topbarRight` below the space.

Removing the `&nbsp;` did the trick for me.  You should use a margin instead of a space to put spacing between the header elements.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! Do you use any inspector for ie7 like firebug for firefox?

Comment: I used IE 9 and put it in the IE 7 browser mode using the built-in developer tools.  This usually works for seeing how a site works in IE 7, but there are some quirky differences.